# What is the cause of "pivot_table() got an unexpected keyword argument"

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I'm trying some sample code from a book that I got.  The book is titled 'Python for Data Analysis'.  The book says to go to the following link and download the data: http://www.grouplens.org/node/73

I did that.  I ran the following scripts successfully.

```
import pandas as pd
unames = ['user_id', 'gender', 'age', 'occupation', 'zip']
users = pd.read_table('C:\\Users\\Excel\\Desktop\\Briefcase\\PDFs\\Python\\SampleData\\movies.dat', sep='::', header=None, names=unames)
rnames = ['user_id', 'movie_id', 'rating', 'timestamp']
ratings = pd.read_table('C:\\Users\\Excel\\Desktop\\Briefcase\\PDFs\\Python\\SampleData\\movies.dat', sep='::', header=None, names=rnames)
mnames = ['movie_id', 'title', 'genres']
movies = pd.read_table('C:\\Users\\Excel\\Desktop\\Briefcase\\PDFs\\Python\\SampleData\\movies.dat', sep='::', header=None, names=mnames)
data = pd.merge(pd.merge(ratings, users), movies)
```

Everything works fine!  Now, the book says try this:

```
mean_ratings = data.pivot_table('rating', rows='title', cols='gender', aggfunc='mean')
```

That line gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
    mean_ratings = data.pivot_table('rating', rows='title', cols='gender', aggfunc='mean')
TypeError: pivot_table() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rows'
```

I don't know what is wrong here.  How can I interpret this?

Comment: Learning from books is great, but the software world tends to move very quick, so you should get used to consulting online documentation. I'm not sure why the book suggested it, but [`pivot_table()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) doesn't take a `rows` argument.

Comment: Oh, of course, online documentation!  Google gave me this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html

From that, I got the following to work:
mean_ratings = data.pivot_table('rating', columns='gender', aggfunc='mean')

I think it makes sense now.  Thanks Jonathon.

Comment: Feel free to post an answer to your own question.